# draw and cla in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am plotting multiple arrows using `matplotlib pyplot arrow` function. It's plottting just fine. After a set of arrows have been plotted, I need to recompute the arrow locations and plot them again. I am using `draw` for that. So essentially I draw and plot arrows in a loop and clear the plot using `cla()` after a time interval. Here's what I don't understand: when I substitute `time.sleep(1)` function with `raw_input()` that waits for a key input, it works just fine but when I use the `time.sleep(1)` there is no plot shown at all.

Here's my code(I hv removed some presumably irrelevant stuff):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as PP
import time
fig = PP.figure()
fig.show()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)   
for i in range(30):
    for i in range(100):
      pass
      # loc = some code to recalculate arrow locations
    for x,y in loc.iteritems():
        ax.arrow( x, y,.05,.05, fc="k", ec="k",head_width=0.04, head_length=0.04 )
    PP.draw()
    #raw_input()
    time.sleep(1)
    PP.cla()
```